# ZipFile puts all parent directories inside newly created zip file

Tags: python, zip, os.walk, python-zipfile

I want to create a zipfile from a select few individual files. Here is my code so far:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from os import walk

name = 'Mia'

allFiles = next(walk("C:\\Users\\jack_l\\Documents\\Image-Line\\FL Studio\\Projects\\finished\\UPLOAD"), (None, None, []))[2]

allStemFiles = []

for counter in range(len(allFiles)):
    if str('STEMS - '+name) in allFiles[counter]:
        allStemFiles.append(allFiles[counter])

myZipFile = ZipFile(r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\Image-Line\FL Studio\Projects\finished\UPLOAD\beatTitle.zip', 'w')

for counter in range(len(allStemFiles)):
    myZipFile.write('C:\\Users\\jack_l\\Documents\\Image-Line\\FL Studio\\Projects\\finished\\UPLOAD\\'+allStemFiles[counter])

myZipFile.close()
```

My issue is that it does create a zipfile in the correct directory (C:..../UPLOAD), but the zipfile it creates contains 8 layers of folders over the files. Like the zip file contains a folder called Users, which contains a folder called jack_l, and so on until a folder called UPLOAD contains my files.

I tried to fix this by writing:

```
myZipFile.write(allStemFiles[counter])
```

instead of:

```
myZipFile.write('C:\\Users\\jack_l\\Documents\\Image-Line\\FL Studio\\Projects\\finished\\UPLOAD\\'+allStemFiles[counter])
```

but then I get the following error:
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Just to re-iterate; I want a zipfile only containing the files (no folders whatsoever). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the working directory to the base directory of files to be archived first so that all paths become relative to the base directory:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os

name = 'Mia'

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\jack_l\\Documents\\Image-Line\\FL Studio\\Projects\\finished\\UPLOAD")

allFiles = next(os.walk("."), (None, None, []))[2]

allStemFiles = []

for counter in range(len(allFiles)):
    if str('STEMS - '+name) in allFiles[counter]:
        allStemFiles.append(allFiles[counter])

myZipFile = ZipFile('beatTitle.zip', 'w')

for counter in range(len(allStemFiles)):
    myZipFile.write(allStemFiles[counter])

myZipFile.close()
```